# How to trigger swiftui function in uikit

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit

I use Swiftui in UIViewController to display the content. There is a form in Swiftui. After filling in the form, click the Run button on the navigation bar of UIViewController to trigger the function execution in Swiftui.

The UIViewController code is as bellow:

```swift
import UIKit
import SwiftUI

class TestVC: UIViewController {
    var testView1: TestView1?
    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.setupData()
        self.setupUI()
    }
    
    func setupData() {
    }
    
    func setupUI() {
        self.navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false
        setupNavBar()
        
        let contentView = TestView1()
        let hostVC = UIHostingController(rootView: contentView)
        guard let hostView = hostVC.view else {
            return
        }
        view.addSubview(hostView)
        hostView.frame = self.view.frame
        self.testView1 = contentView
    }

    func setupNavBar() {
        let item1 = UIBarButtonItem(customView: self.runBtn)
        navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [item1]
    }
    
    lazy var runBtn: UIButton  = {
        let btn = UIButton()
        btn.setTitle("Run", for: .normal)
        btn.setTitleColor(.blue, for: .normal)
        btn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(runBtnAction), for: .touchUpInside)
        return btn
    }()
    
    
    @objc func runBtnAction() {
        self.testView1?.run2()
    }
}
```

The SwiftUI view code is as bellow:

```swift
import SwiftUI

struct TestView1: View {
    @State private var inputContent: String = "init"
    
    var body: some View {
        return VStack(spacing: 20) {
            ScrollView(showsIndicators: false) {
                Button {
                    run1()
                } label: {
                    Text("Run")
                        .foregroundColor(.blue)
                }

                TextEditor(text: $inputContent)
                    .foregroundColor(.black)
                    .background(Color.gray.opacity(0.2))
            }
            
        }
        .foregroundColor(.black)
        .background(Color.white)
    }
    
    
    public func run1() {
        inputContent = "run test 1"
        print("run1 inputContent is \(inputContent)")
    }
    
    public func run2() {
        // inputContent should be "run test 1" but output is "init"
        print("run2 before inputContent is \(inputContent)")
        inputContent = "run test 2"
        // inputContent should be "run test 2" but output is still "init"
        print("run2 after inputContent is \(inputContent)")
    }
}
```

First click "Run" button in SwiftUI, it print "run1 inputContent is run test 1
", which meets expectations.
However, when click "Run" button in TestVC, it always print "run2 inputContent is init
", not the modified new value.

How can I correctly call Swiftui's functions in uikit?

Comment: SwiftUI views are structs, and therefore it isn't safe to try and hold a reference in a property.  You should use a model object, which is a reference type (class instance) and pass this model to your SwiftUI view.  Your SwiftUI view can then update the model and there is no need for the UIKit code to call any function in the SwiftUI view